# Docker doesn't persist created file

Tags: docker

I use the following Dockerfile to setup a container:

```
FROM proycon/lamachine:latest
EXPOSE 5000
USER root
MAINTAINER Joey Kaan <joey@treehouse.nl>
COPY vacancies/vacancies.sql vacancies.sql
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cat vacancies.sql | sqlite3 vacancies.db"]
WORKDIR /usr/src/Characteristics/src/Services/InternshipService
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/Characteristics/src/Services/InternshipService/web.py"]
```

The RUN command is showing odd behaviour. The command executes just fine without any errors, it also creates the vacancies.db but it's empty.

I would assume Docker creates the vacancies.db based on the vacancies.sql but it doesn't. However, if I execute that command twice it shows an error that indicates the database has been created.

Part of the error is:

```
ERROR: near line 139832: UNIQUE constraint failed: vacancy.id
```

One other important thing to note is that I set up a volume that maps my project directory to the directory `/usr/src/Characteristics`. I think it may have something to do with this but after debugging, I still can't find the issue.

Comment: Are you mapping any storage in the docker run command?

Comment: No, I do not. I just set up a mapping by using the -v flag when using `docker run`.

Comment: Whats the full run command you're using.

Comment: The full command is: `docker run -v ~/Development/IE/Characteristics/src:/usr/src/Characteristics/src -it jk/ml`

Comment: on a sidenote `USER root` may be removed, as by default, you are root

Comment: The error appears to be a sql error pointing to line 139832 of the file, the vacancy.id is duplicated from a prior line. I recommend getting the sqlite3 command to run properly outside of the container before trying to Dockerize it.